# How can I configure dimension to ignore specific value

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, olap, olap-cube, mondrian

I have an existing fact table and I need to modeling an OLAP cube using Mondrian Schema.
Fact table has several columns with the primary key of dimension table but unluckily there are row with dimension value "0" with the convention of "all"

Example with only one dimension: student_id:

```
| student_id |       exams
+------------+-------------
|         0  |          23
|     20131  |          15
|     20168  |           2
|     20468  |           6
```

student table

```
  id   | name
-------+-----------
 20131 | John
 20168 | Daid
 20468 | Peter
 20629 | Paul
 22344 | Micheal
```

My schema is:

```
<Schema name="students">
  <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" name="StudentDimension">
    <Hierarchy name="Student" visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id">
      <Table name="student" schema="public" alias="" />
      <Level name="Nome" visible="true" column="name" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" />
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Cube name="studentCube" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="students_cube" schema="public" />
    <DimensionUsage source="StudentDimension" name="StudentUsage" visible="true" foreignKey="student_id" />
    <Measure name="Exams" column="exams" datatype="Numeric" aggregator="sum" visible="true" />
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

My problem is that executing the query:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Exams]} ON COLUMNS,
    {[StudentUsage.Student].[All StudentUsage.Student]} ON ROWS 
FROM [studentCube]
```

I have the result "46": the sum of all the exams included the row with student_id = 0.

I'd like to exclude in the schema the measures associated to dimensions with value "0". Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Exams]} ON COLUMNS,
    {
     [StudentUsage.Student].[All StudentUsage.Student] - 
     [StudentUsage.Student].[All StudentUsage.Student].&[0]
    } ON ROWS 
FROM [studentCube]
```

Or try:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Exams]} ON COLUMNS,
    EXCEPT
       (
        [StudentUsage.Student].[All StudentUsage.Student] , 
        [StudentUsage.Student].[All StudentUsage.Student].&[0]
       ) ON ROWS 
FROM [studentCube]
```

Comment: I get this error: "MDX object '[StudentUsage.Student].[All StudentUsage.Student].&[0]' not found in cube 'studentCube'"

Comment: What is the fully qualified member name of this member.."there are row with dimension value "0" with the convention of "all""?